# Angular 5 Service Worker not working

Tags: angular5, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I try to add service worker to my project after updating to angular 5 and have some problems. I add imports to app.module.ts:

```
import {ServiceWorkerModule} from '@angular/service-worker';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
...
environment.production ? ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js') : [],
```

execute `$ ng set apps.0.serviceWorker=true` to allow service workers in project

generate config:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/index.html"
        ],
        "versionedFiles": [
          "/*.bundle.css",
          "/*.bundle.js",
          "/*.chunk.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "/",
        "/main",
        "/login",
        "/select-content"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And manifest:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "short_name": "App",
  "start_url": "/login",
  "theme_color": "#00a2e8",
  "background_color": "#00a2e8",
  "display": "standalone",
 "icons": [
  {
   "src": "assets\/icons\/android-icon-36x36.png",
   "sizes": "36x36",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "0.75"
  },
  {
   "src": "assets\/icons\/android-icon-48x48.png",
   "sizes": "48x48",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "1.0"
  },
  {
   "src": "assets\/icons\/android-icon-72x72.png",
   "sizes": "72x72",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "1.5"
  },
  {
   "src": "assets\/icons\/android-icon-96x96.png",
   "sizes": "96x96",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "2.0"
  },
  {
   "src": "assets\/icons\/android-icon-144x144.png",
   "sizes": "144x144",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "3.0"
  },
  {
   "src": "assets\/icons\/android-icon-192x192.png",
   "sizes": "192x192",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "4.0"
  }
 ]
}
```

Then build it in production:

```
ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false
```

Http-server run in SSL mode, but lsit of service workers in chrome dev-tools is clear. What's wrong? May be this flags broke it --aot=false --build-optimizer=false?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1923

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Seems to be a problem in registering service worker in module where also importing AngularFire2. I found solution how to register SW in main.ts, that's work:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('ngsw-worker.js');
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! I was struggling with this for a few time!

Comment: I'm not using AngularFire2, but I had the same problem and this was the solution.

Comment: It worked for me too..though i could not find out which package is creating issue in registering the service worker.

Comment: I don't use AngularFire2, but this solved my problem as well. Figuring out which package caused the issue seems like a daunting task... Thank you!

Comment: Actually, in my code service worker is running on my machine when i run it locally. But, it's not running on remote machine if i run it on another machine having same network access.

Comment: @MDM try adding the application full path while setting the `ngsw-worker.js`  in `app.module` something like this `path_to\app\ngsw-worker.js`

Comment: This solution works fine but after adding this, the server side rendering stop working in my angular project. Any help?

Comment: This might be a better solution if you're using Angular 8 and oidc client: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57599970/882912