# Angular 7 - service worker not registered

Tags: angular, angular-cli, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular7

I did everything as written in "https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started" to make my application PWA.

Used exactly this commands:

```
ng add @angular/pwa

npm install http-server -g

ng build --prod

http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist
```

Then I opened this url on Chrome (in incognito)

http://127.0.0.1:8080

When I open tools for developers (f12) > Applications > Service Workers there is no service worker available and website don't work when I set offline there.

Additional info about my angular app:

package.json: (the most important ones)

```
"@angular/core": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/pwa": "^0.10.6",
"@angular/service-worker": "^7.0.4",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.6",
"@angular/cli": "^7.0.6",
```

Comment: have yout ried using firefox? Are you trying to cache dynamic assets or urls?

Comment: Because for now I tried just to make basic functionality work, you can see what should be cached by default here https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#whats-being-cached

Comment: @tmz Yes, I understand. Have you tried using firefox to see if there is a service worker? Does your site have static content or only dynamic content?

Comment: @ams I havent tried to use firefox, but I don't believe that this problem is related with chrome browser. Both, static/dynamic content.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It seems the service worker setup is broken for the @angular/cli@7.1.4:

As a temporary solution you can register it manually yourself by modifying the file **src/main.ts** (Once fixed you can remove the manual service worker registration.):

```
.....

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

PS: Github issue created: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13351

PS: Github issue #2 created: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15025

Comment: broken in CLI: 7.3.1 also

Comment: which @angular/cli version is stable so that we can use service worker

Comment: I think it is not about that serviceworker is broken. I believe that your application is not stable. For example setinterval or settiemout will broke angular stablity. You should use something else than those.

Comment: new issue created, hope it won't get closed this time  : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15025

Comment: Just want to mention that these issues happens mostly because your angular app is unstable, due to things like `setInterval`. Since Angular 8, we are given the option to use a different `registrationStrategy` which solves this problem.

In `app.module.ts`, use `ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { registrationStrategy: 'registerWithDelay', enabled: environment.production })`

You can check out the code documentation in [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/service-worker/src/module.ts#L46-L71)

Comment: Exactly. The service worker doesn't register in Angular v8 as well. And this fix did not work in my case.

Comment: Update on previous comment : The service worker doesn't register in Angular v8 as well. And this fix works with deployment on IIS but not with http-server CLI.

Answer (score 39):

artemisian's solution works but it's a hack, and you're not sure if it will work in the future.

**A better solution**

There is a 'registrationStrategy' setting which has to do with angular waiting with the registration until your app is 'stable'. Now if you have a bunch of stuff loading while starting your app (authenticating and building websocket connections) angular apparently thinks your app never is stable.

Fortunately you can override the registrationStrategy to `registerImmediately` like so:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' }),
```

See for the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwRegistrationOptions#registrationStrategy)

After this the serviceworker will load, whatever the state of your app. There's also an option to pass an observable, so you can have it loaded whenever you think it's right.

Comment: It's a handy tip but only became available in Angular V8.

Comment: Awesome. I could not figure out why the service worker wouldn't register. I have stuff that I need to use an infinite interval/function for so...

Comment: **Update**: I actually didn't need that option anymore when I replaced all my `setInterval(...)`'s with rxjs' `timer(...)` ! https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!!! I'm using oidc client and couldn't figure out why it wouldn't register. I wanted to give your GitHub answer thumbs up https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13351, but they locked the issue! :-(

Answer (score 12):

Be aware that browsers does not register service workers for HTTP **unless it's localhost**.

Running **http-server**, the console showed that the application will be served from the following URLs: 
http://10.40.59.29:8080, http://127.0.0.1:8080, http://192.168.255.209:8080.

Don't forget to replace the IP address to **localhost** like http://localhost:8080/

Comment: In Google Chrome you can set trusted origins for testing in chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure

It's way useful if you use the Angular behind a dockered nginx service

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to edit this line: '!isDevMode()' to 'isDevMode()' so that it registers in the localhost which is in dev mode.

```js
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      // enabled: !isDevMode(),
      enabled: true,
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
      // registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately'
    }),
```